# R: Subset data with only most recent observation per ID

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I currently have an issue with an assignment.

We analyze YT trending data which is structured to following

We have the observations the in the row and things like video id, category id, title, trending date and so on in the columns.

The task is to keep the most recent oberservation per video_id (a video is sometimes several days in the trends and we want only the latest observation(row).

I tried it so far with:

```
newDataframe <- aggregate(trending_date ~ video_id, data=df, FUN=max)
```

While it did the job I does not have all the other variables expect trending date and ID which I need, therefore I thought about binding it together with the old? dataframe, but I have no idea how I should do this without having the unwanted older observations in it.

I highly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the economics data from the `ggplot2` package to make the answer reproducible:

```
library(data.table)

econ <- as.data.table(ggplot2::economics_long)
econ
##             date variable  value      value01
##    1: 1967-07-01      pce  507.4 0.0000000000
##    2: 1967-08-01      pce  510.5 0.0002660008
##    3: 1967-09-01      pce  516.3 0.0007636797
##    4: 1967-10-01      pce  512.9 0.0004719369
##    5: 1967-11-01      pce  518.1 0.0009181318
##   ---                                        
## 2866: 2014-12-01 unemploy 8688.0 0.4739085814
## 2867: 2015-01-01 unemploy 8979.0 0.4968816610
## 2868: 2015-02-01 unemploy 8705.0 0.4752506513
## 2869: 2015-03-01 unemploy 8575.0 0.4649877635
## 2870: 2015-04-01 unemploy 8549.0 0.4629351859
```

This command (which uses the `data.table` package) gets the most recent row for each variable:

```
econ[order(-date), .SD[1], by=variable]
##    variable       date    value   value01
## 1:      pce 2015-04-01  12158.9 0.9997769
## 2:      pop 2015-04-01 320887.0 1.0000000
## 3:  psavert 2015-04-01      5.6 0.2450331
## 4:  uempmed 2015-04-01     11.7 0.3632075
## 5: unemploy 2015-04-01   8549.0 0.4629352
```

**Explanation**

- `econ` The table to subset
- `order(-date)` Sorts the rows by the `date` column, in descending order (newest to oldest)

  - To sort in ascending order: `order(date)`
  - To sort by multiple columns: `order(variable, date, etc.)`
- `by=variable` Group the data by the `variable` column
- `.SD` A "**S**ubset of **D**ata", which is a special table that can be accessed when using the `by` argument; it is the `econ` table, but split into a separate table for each value of `variable`
- `.SD[1]` Get the first row of the `.SD` table

Use the following commands for your example:

```
## Convert the data.frame to a data.table
setDT(df)

## Get the most recent observation per video_id
df[order(-trending_date), .SD[1], by=video_id
```